# Java HotSwap. Block hotswaps from specified developer

Tags: java, hotswap

Sometimes some developers perform hotswap from IntellijIdea `(Ctrl+Shift+F9)` and we have one commons server that has debug port enabled
and they do that on debug in IntelliJ Idea. I have two questions

1. How to limit this possibility for different developers? Is it possible? Some of them doesn't listen, they don't want to wait for new deploy, perform hotswaps and other
   developers has problem in debbuging (different line numbers, non existing code etc). I could block Hotswap for all or only for some ip-numbers if its possible. Or maybe there is some other mechanism?
2. Why if I change one class and on debug do `(Ctrl+Shift+F9)` sometimes only one class is reloaded and sometimes like 10 or more?

The server is Weblogic 12, Java 1.72

Answer (score 1):

Java hot swap uses the remote debugging [JDWP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/jdwp-spec.html) protocol.  This protocol does not provide any authentication mechanisms.  What you can do is use your system's firewall to block all access to the JDWP port that you configured and then only open it up for "allowed" developers.

Comment: It would be too cruel to block them debug port :) Would be great to block hotswapping only though

Comment: It would probably be possible to write a tcp proxy that inspected the JDWP packets and blocked hotswap ones for certain IP addresses ... might be a fun project  if one had the spare time :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are open for extreme solutions you can block access to debug port for any developer who doesn't want to listen and cooperate.

For example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s $OFFENDER_IP -p tcp --destination-port $DEBUG_PORT -j DROP
/sbin/service iptables save
```

Comment: It would be too cruel to block them debug port :) Would be great to block hotswapping only though